# how to add property in object in increasing order in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array of objects .In Objects some have `shortkeys` property and some don't have `shortkeys` property. I want to add `shortkeys` property to all objects .
Important thing is that I need to give unique `shortkeys` to all object.

Those objects which don't have `shortkeys` will follow these conditions

- if object don't have`shortkeys` than it assign `shortkeys` starting from **1-9**  like that 'alt+1' ,'alt+2'...'alt+9'.
- After `9` I need to assign `0` property to object .
- Then I need to assign `a-z` like that 'alt+a','alt+b'
- Important I need to skip all `shortkeys` which is already defined example 'alt+m' .so that every object has unique property.

Here is my code 
https://jsfiddle.net/krzz9zmf/

```
var arr=[
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+m"},
  {name:"c_1"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+t"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+c"},
  {name:"wes_2"},
  {name:"ncv_3"},
  {name:"sghb_4"},
  {name:"ijo_5"},
  {name:"nhio_6"},
  {name:"jion_7"},
  {name:"chudoi_8"},
  {name:"bdmki_9"},
  {name:"dssd_0"},
  {name:"sdfs_a"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+y"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+e"},
  {name:"sghb_b"},
  {name:"ijo_d"},
  {name:"gsha_e"},
  {name:"asdas_f"},
  {name:"bbb_g"},
  {name:"mko_h"},
  {name:"kioh_i"},
  {name:"qwee_j"},
  {name:"qwee_k"},
  {name:"qwee_l"},
  {name:"qwee_n"},

]

var j =1;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  var obj =arr[i];
  if (!'shortkeys' in myObj){
    //add shorkeys start from 1-9 then 0 and then a-z.In other words need to assign shortcut key like that 'alt+1','alt+2'....'alt+0'''alt+a','alt+b'...'alt+z';
    //some of the objects already define shortkeys example 'alt+m' .so I need to skip these shortcut key .so that each item have unique shortcut.
    myObj.shortkeys= 'alt+'+j;
    j++;
    if(j==10){
      j=0
    }
    if(j==1){
      myObj.shortkeys='alt+a';
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
{name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+m"},
{name:"c_1",,shortkeys:"alt+1"},
{name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+t"},
{name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+c"},
{name:"wes_2",shortkeys:"alt+2"},
{name:"ncv_3",,shortkeys:"alt+3"},
{name:"sghb_4",shortkeys:"alt+4"},
{name:"ijo_5",shortkeys:"alt+5"},
{name:"nhio_6",shortkeys:"alt+6"},
{name:"jion_7",shortkeys:"alt+7"},
{name:"chudoi_8",shortkeys:"alt+8"},
{name:"bdmki_9",shortkeys:"alt+9"},
{name:"dssd_0",shortkeys:"alt+0"},
{name:"sdfs_a",shortkeys:"alt+a"},
{name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+y"},
{name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+e"},
{name:"sghb_b",shortkeys:"alt+b"},
{name:"ijo_d",shortkeys:"alt+d"},
{name:"gsha_e",shortkeys:"alt+e"},
{name:"asdas_f",shortkeys:"alt+f"},
{name:"bbb_g",shortkeys:"alt+g"},
{name:"mko_h",shortkeys:"alt+h"},
{name:"kioh_i",shortkeys:"alt+i"},
{name:"qwee_j",shortkeys:"alt+j"},
{name:"qwee_k",shortkeys:"alt+k"},
{name:"qwee_l",shortkeys:"alt+l"},
{name:"qwee_n",shortkeys:"alt+n"},

]
```

Comment: Just wondering, what after `alt+z`?

Comment: I'm not sure if you've really put some effort in what you did (I hope you did), but there are so many errors and missing parts that I cannot pretend to spend too much time on it. Here is a working solution (from your fiddle): https://jsfiddle.net/krzz9zmf/2/ . Note that you weren't neither checking properly, nor replacing the values and not even referencing to the right variable (check your console, **it tells you if something goes wrong**). You were referencing myObj instead of obj. (I didn't even check that all the results are correct because the logic is missing, this is the best I can do)

Comment: You didn't say what your question actually is, but your code has `var obj`, but then you use `myObj` instead.

Comment: ...If you just need to know how to increment letters, `a` has a character code of `97`, so just start there and increment and use `String.fromCharCode(n)`

Comment: @A.Wolff after 'alt-z' nothing happen. don't add shortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through and remove the chars that exists as keys then go back through and add what remains

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/krzz9zmf/8/

```
var alpha_num_array = [
'1','2','3','4',
'5','6','7','8','9',
'0',
'a','b','c','d','e',
'f','g','h','i','j',
'k','l','m','n','o',
'p','q','r','s','t',
'u','v','w','x','y',
'z'];

key_arr.map(function(k){
  if(!k.shortkeys) return;

  var key = k.shortkeys.split('+')[1];
  var key_index = alpha_num_array.indexOf(key);
  alpha_num_array.splice(key_index, 1);

})

key_arr = key_arr.map(function(k){
  if(k.shortkeys) return k;

  k.shortkeys = 'alt+'+alpha_num_array[0];
  alpha_num_array.shift();
  return k;
})

console.log(key_arr);
```

Comment: that is not expected output..please remove this answer

Comment: try again. I reordered the array so it will be 1-9,0,a-z order

Comment: please share jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr=[
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+m"},
  {name:"c_1"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+t"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+c"},
  {name:"wes_2"},
  {name:"ncv_3"},
  {name:"sghb_4"},
  {name:"ijo_5"},
  {name:"nhio_6"},
  {name:"jion_7"},
  {name:"chudoi_8"},
  {name:"bdmki_9"},
  {name:"dssd_0"},
  {name:"sdfs_a"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+4"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+e"},
  {name:"sghb_b"},
  {name:"ijo_d"},
  {name:"gsha_e"},
  {name:"asdas_f"},
  {name:"bbb_g"},
  {name:"mko_h"},
  {name:"kioh_i"},
  {name:"qwee_j"},
  {name:"qwee_k"},
  {name:"qwee_l"},
  {name:"qwee_n"},
];

//possible shortkeys reversed so we can pop them off
var keys = [
  '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'
  ,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'
  ,'k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t'
  ,'u','v','w','x','y','z'].reverse();
//elements without a shortkeys
var tagsWithoutShortcuts = arr.filter(function(element){ return typeof element.shortkeys === 'undefined'; });

console.log(keys);
console.log(tagsWithoutShortcuts);

tagsWithoutShortcuts.forEach(function(tag){
  var key = keys.pop();
  //while key is already used, get another
  while (arr.filter(function(element){ return element.shortkeys === 'alt+'+ key; }).length) key = keys.pop();
  //put the shortkeys on the tag
  tag.shortkeys = 'alt+'+ key;
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: your output is not expected output.so please remove this answer

Comment: I put alt+4 in the arr[] at the start.  Check again.  `{name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+4"},`  Otherwise your test starting data didn't have an element with an alt+# to test that the solution would skip a number.

Answer (score 1):

The errors with your existing attempt *(aside from not getting the letters you want)* was that...

- you were using the wrong variable name `myObj` after having declared `var obj`
- you had `if (!'shortkeys' in myObj){` instead of `if (!('shortkeys' in myObj)){`
- you were failing to look for existing `shortkeys` before assigning one

In this code, I...

- added an object that tracks all used shortkeys, including the currently existing ones
- added a loop that keeps looking for a unique shortkey until one is found
- added a `alpha` variable to be used to get the `a-z` character
- added an `OUTER` label to the main `for` loop so that we can break the loop if we exceed the letter `z`. The label is needed because we're breaking from the inner `do-while` loop.

```js
var arr=[
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+m"}, {name:"c_1"}, {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+t"}, {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+c"},
  {name:"wes_2"}, {name:"ncv_3"}, {name:"sghb_4"}, {name:"ijo_5"}, {name:"nhio_6"}, {name:"jion_7"},
  {name:"chudoi_8"}, {name:"bdmki_9"}, {name:"dssd_0"}, {name:"sdfs_a"}, {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+y"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+e"}, {name:"sghb_b"}, {name:"ijo_d"}, {name:"gsha_e"}, {name:"asdas_f"},
  {name:"bbb_g"}, {name:"mko_h"}, {name:"kioh_i"}, {name:"qwee_j"}, {name:"qwee_k"}, {name:"qwee_l"}, {name:"qwee_n"}
]

var j = 1;
var alpha = 'a'.charCodeAt(0); // Number for the 'a-z' chars
var z = 'z'.charCodeAt(0); // Number for the 'z' character
var shorts = {}; // Holds all shortkeys to avoid duplicates
var short = "";

// First gather all the existing shortkeys
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].shortkeys) {
    shorts[arr[i].shortkeys] = arr[i].shortkeys
  }
}

OUTER:
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var myObj = arr[i];
  
  if (!('shortkeys' in myObj)) {
    // We want to make sure that our "short" is not yet used.
    do {
      if (j < 10) {
        short = 'alt+' + j
        j++;
        
      } else if (j == 10) {
        short = 'alt+0'
        j++;
        
      } else if (alpha <= z) {
        short = 'alt+' + String.fromCharCode(alpha);
        alpha++;
        
      } else {
       break OUTER; // We've moved beyond 'z', so just quit.
      }
    } while(short in shorts)
    
    // Track the new shortkey, and assign it
    shorts[short] = short
    myObj.shortkeys = short
  }
}

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4)
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

***Note...***

- Your expected output has a mistake; it has `alt+e` twice.
- There's no need to manually create an Array of values since characters map to numbers